# Found no valid, enabled rules for this file type and file path in the resolved configuration

Tags: angular, typescript, eslint, tslint, angular15

There is gitlab runner pipeline for code-verification which is using script `tslint **/**/*.ts -t json -o report.json || true`. I have migrated my angular project from version 12 to 15, tslint to eslint and in the logs I'm getting error like "**Tried to lint e2e/src/app.e2e-spec.ts but found no valid, enabled rules for this file type and file path in the resolved configuration**."
I have tried approach like removing directory of node_module or patterns removing in **eslintrc.json** file but still getting same error.

```json
{
  "name": "parsing-portal",
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "patch-package",
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "build:ci": "ng build --configuration=ci",
    "build:qa": "ng build --configuration=qa",
    "build:prod": "ng build --configuration=production",
    "test": "ng test --source-map=true",
    "test:ci": "ng test --browsers ChromeHeadless --watch=false",
    "test:xvfb": "xvfb-run npm run test:ci",
    "test:coverage": "ng version",
    "test:xvfb-coverage": "ng version",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "analyze": "ng build --configuration production --stats-json && webpack-bundle-analyzer dist/stats-es2015.json"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^15.2.10",
    "@angular/cdk": "15.2.9",
    "@angular/common": "15.2.10",
    "@angular/compiler": "15.2.10",
    "@angular/core": "15.2.10",
    "@angular/forms": "15.2.10",
    "@angular/localize": "^15.2.10",
    "@angular/material": "15.2.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "15.2.10",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "15.2.10",
    "@angular/router": "^15.2.10",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.13.0",
    "@mat-datetimepicker/core": "^3.0.2",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^5.2.1",
    "@ng-select/ng-select": "^3.7.3",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^11.0.1",
    "@swimlane/ngx-datatable": "^16.0.3",
    "@types/openfin": "43.0.1",
    "ag-grid-angular": "26.0.0",
    "ag-grid-community": "26.0.0",
    "angular-datatables": "12.0.0",
    "angular-resize-event": "^1.2.1",
    "angular-slickgrid": "^2.17.10",
    "angular2-multiselect-dropdown": "^4.6.3",
    "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
    "datatables.net": "^1.10.20",
    "datatables.net-dt": "^1.10.20",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.2",
    "flatpickr": "^4.6.6",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "ini": "^2.0.0",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "lodash.isequal": "^4.5.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.0",
    "ng-busy": "^8.0.0",
    "ng-multiselect-dropdown": "^0.2.10",
    "ng-pick-datetime": "^7.0.0",
    "ng2-completer": "^9.0.1",
    "ng2-search-filter": "^0.5.1",
    "ng2-smart-table": "^1.4.0",
    "ngx-toastr": "^11.3.3",
    "node-fetch": "^2.7.0",
    "patch-package": "^6.2.2",
    "rxjs": "~7.8.1",
    "tslib": "2.3.1",
    "zone.js": "0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^15.2.10",
    "@angular-eslint/builder": "15.2.1",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "15.2.1",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "15.2.1",
    "@angular-eslint/schematics": "15.2.1",
    "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "15.2.1",
    "@angular/cli": "15.2.10",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "15.2.10",
    "@angular/language-service": "15.2.10",
    "@types/datatables.net": "^1.10.18",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.3.32",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.200",
    "@types/node": "^16.10.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "5.48.2",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "5.48.2",
    "eslint": "^8.33.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "6.3.4",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "3.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "4.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "1.7.0",
    "protractor": "7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "typescript": "~4.9.5",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "4.4.2"
  }
}
```

and My .eslintrc.json looks like

```json
{
  "root": true,
  "ignorePatterns": [
    "projects/**/*"
    
  ],
  "overrides": [
    {
      "files": [
      "*.ts"
      ],
      "parserOptions": {
        "project": [
          "tsconfig.json",
          "e2e/tsconfig.json"
        ],
        "createDefaultProgram": true
      },
      "extends": [
        "plugin:@angular-eslint/recommended",
        "plugin:@angular-eslint/template/process-inline-templates"
      ],
      "rules": {
        "@angular-eslint/component-selector": [
          "error",
          {
            "prefix": "app",
            "style": "kebab-case",
            "type": "element"
          }
        ],
        "@angular-eslint/directive-selector": [
          "warn",
          {
            "prefix": "app",
            "style": "camelCase",
            "type": "attribute"
          }
        ],
        "@angular-eslint/no-empty-lifecycle-method": "off",
        "@typescript-eslint/tslint/config": ["off"]
      }
    },
    {
      "files": [
        "*.html"
      ],
      "extends": [
        "plugin:@angular-eslint/template/recommended"
      ],
      "rules": {
        "@angular-eslint/template/eqeqeq": ["warn"]
    }
    }
  ]
}
```

I have tried multiple approach like remove pattern. What should I do to resolve this issue. Any update would be appreciated.